# Nifi RouteonAttribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I need help in dynamically updating the RouteonAttribute processor properties using Nifi.

For example, if I send `Sensor_value:50` the RouteonAttribute must automatically set a property like

```
${Sensor_value:equals(50)}
```

Can you guys help me?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a dynamic property with the name of your desired relationship and the Expression Language expression `${Sensor_value:equals(50)}` as the value of that property. The User Guide [has an example](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#properties-tab) of how to do this.

Comment: Can it be like this ${Sensor_value:(${Sensor_value})}

Comment: What are you trying to do with that expression? There's no function in between. If you meant `${Sensor_value:equals(${Sensor_value})}` that should always be true. Do you mean that if RouteOnAttribute "sees" a new value for `Sensor_value` then it adds a new relationship? That isn't possible as the dynamic properties must be defined (and populated) before the processor is started.

Comment: Can I update the values in the routeonattribute dynamically ?

Comment: Not while the processor is running, you'd have to stop it, update the property values, and restart